# Ubuntu 13.10 Killed my Desktop computer!

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I need help. I have an HP Pavilion g7 and I was wondering how to fix it. What happened was it originally came with Windows 7, and I upgraded to 8, but today I decided to make the switch from windows to Ubuntu, so I partitioned my hard disk, and backed up everything to one partition, which I don't wanna delete because It contains my backups, and partitioned again. I also kept note, luckilly, of how much free space Windows 8 had. And when I booted to Ubuntu, I gave all of the free space to swap and I deleted the Windows partition (Note: I left the system partition there, that was there maybe after upgrade to 8.) Then, I installed Ubuntu where Windows was originally. It completed install, and I reboot it, then get a suspisious black screen, so I power off the PC, and power it back on, I then get a Light-Blue (Like the color of the sky) screen with white text, it says something like this:

Recovery

A required device cannot be accessed or is not plugged in.

Insert your installation media or contact your system administrator.

I try hitting enter, screen goes black for a split second and re-appears, the same thing happens when I press F8. Is there any way to fix this without completely formatting the hard disk?

(Note: I followed a video by AvoidErrors about dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04, but instead deleted the Windows Partition (Atleast I thought it was due to the amount of space used, all the other partitions were full, except the Windows one, which was half-full.) It was also obvious AvoidErrors was using a Virtual Machine instead of actual hardware.

Comment: Can you boot a live cd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is there any way to fix this without completely formatting the hard disk?"

I don't think so. But maybe you can try to boot a Live CD or Live USB with Ubuntu to see what really happened to the disk partitions.

Comment: I've also noticed after booting to the LiveCD, both the system partition I mentioned and Ubuntu have a folder named "boot" I don't know if I'm right but I'm inferring this happened:

Comment: The computer gets confused when it boots up, and doesn't know where to go, so it goes to system... If I delete that, will it go to Ubuntu?